# How do I "reload" my config file after every test in python?

Tags: python, pytest

I have two tests in which I'm trying to import things from the same myconfig.py file. But I need some variables in myconfig.py to be changed after every test so the next can use a new one.
Is there any possible way to do it?

I already have function that re-writes info and it works correctly, but both tests import the very first version of myconfig.py.

I tried to use fixtures, but it didn't work. I also tried to run/exec myconfig.py before every launch, didn't help either.

I use two same small tests, run them as a package called `test_package`.

```
from myconfig import url, file_name, line_index
from test_package.functions_filee import upgrade_number
from test_package.pages.my_page import MyPageObject
from file_where_info_should be_rewritten import phone_number

def test_rewrite_number(self, browser):
    my_page = MyPageObject(browser, url)
    my_page.go_to_site()
    my_page.input_phone_number(phone_number)
    upgrade_number(file_name, line_index, phone_number)
```

`upgrade_number` function code:

```
def upgrade_number(file_name, line_index, phone_number):
    with open(file_name, 'r+') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        new_number = str(int(phone_number) + 1)
        new_str = f"phone_number = '{new_number}'\n"
        lines[line_index] = new_str 
        f.seek(0)
        f.writelines(lines)
```

File, where info should be rewritten consists of only a single line:
phone_number = "1111111111"

So basically I want the first test to import `1111111111` as a phone number, then increase it to `1111111112` so that the second test can use `1111111112` as its test data.

EDIT: I did it like this

```
import sys
import importlib

importlib.reload(sys.modules['dynamic_vars'])

from dynamic_vars import *
```

Eventually I gave up on this method of making new phone number for every test, but maybe it will be helpful for anyone

Comment: Hi, can you send your test_script.py please?

Comment: I updated in the post

Comment: To answer quickly: try to import inside your tests functions to reload

Comment: But a lot of lack of good practices here: You should use the module unittest, then create a test file to change during your tests and finally delete it at the end

Comment: thanks for your answers. as for unittest: it's inconvenience for me to change everything now, but I'll come to this if nothing else works for me

Answer (score 0):

The classical pattern for this is called *Test setup*. In pytest you have [`setup_method`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/xunit_setup.html#method-and-function-level-setup-teardown) which you can implement to reload your config and it will be done before each test is executed.

Similarly, you can use `teardown_method` to run code after each test. Your test can also set a class variable so each invocation of `setup_method` or `teardown_method` knows which value to use.

**BUT**

You should not do what you explain here. This makes tests dependent on each other which is a very problematic antipattern. Instead, make each test setup what it needs explicitly at the beginning. So, if a second test needs `1111111112` as its input data, specify this at the beginning of the test - by calling an utility function that will prepare the config appropriately.

This not only makes the tests independent - it also makes them more readable, as it's clear at the beginning of the test what the scenario is.

Comment: Thatnks for your answer! I don't necessarily need to use exactly 1111111112 in the second test. The point is to make next one +1 from the previous so that I will not have similar phone numbers for users

Comment: and can't setup and teardown methods be replaced by the fixture?

Comment: Your `class Test` is already a fixture. If you want have different phone numbers in each test, then just use different phone numbers. What you explain is seriously against unit-testing best practices. I'm fairly sure you don't need that. Focus on what logic you want to cover with the test, and what scenario do you want to explain to the reader of the test. For example: "Given this [phone_number] when I execute [this behavior of my code] the result is [this]". Nothing more, nothing less - each test on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try not to make things complicated